# Decomposition of a finite extension of $k(x_1,...,x_n) $ into separable/inseparable parts

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, extension-field

I'm reading Janos Kolloar's Lecture on Resolution of Singularities and have an question about an argument used in the proof of Theorem 1.33 (page 25):

> THEOREM 1.33 Let $S$ be an integral domain that is finitely generated over a field $k$, and let $F \subset Frac(S)$ be a finite field extensionof it's quotient field. Then the normalization of $S$ in $F$ is finite over $S$.

the proof strategy is: By Noether normalization theorem $S$ is finite over $R=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ thus it suffuce to consider the finite field extension $k(x_1,...,x_n) \subset F$.

> ***Proof.*** [...] $F$ is a finite extension of $k(x_1,...,x_n)$ so there is a finite purely inseparable extension $E/k(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $EF/E$ is separable. (???) Every finite purely inseparable extension of $k(x_1,...,x_n)$ is contained in a field $k'(x_1^{p^{-m}},...,x_n^{p^{-m}})$, where $k'/k$ is finite and purely inseparable (???) [...]

Questions:

Q_1: Why the author talks explicitly about finite purely inseparable extension $E/k(x_1,...,x_n)$ such that $EF/E$ is separable? Why he not simply says that $F$ *contains* an intermediate field $E$ such that extension $E/k(x_1,...,x_n)$ is finite purely inseparable and $F/E$ is separable? Or is this in general wrong claim? That is why we need the field $EF$ in the game?

Q_2: Why every finite purely inseparable extension of $k(x_1,...,x_n)$ is contained in a field $k'(x_1^{p^{-m}},...,x_n^{p^{-m}})$, where $k'/k$ is finite and purely inseparable?

Comment: Given a finite field extension $L/K$ then $a\in L$ is purely inseparable over $K$ iff its $K$-minimal polynomial has only one root. The purely inseparable elements form a subfield $L/I/K$ and $[I:K],[L:I]$ divide $[L:K]$ thus $I/K, L/K$ are finitely generated as fields and $L/I$ is separable because  $b\in \overline{L}$ is $I$-conjugate to $c\in L$ iff it is $K$-conjugate to $c$. How does it help for showing the integral closure of $S$ is a finitely generated $S$-algebra?

Comment: @reuns: I omitted some parts of the proof which I understood. Later the author shows that $k'[x_1^{p^{-m}},...,x_n^{p^{-m}}]$ is the normalization of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ in $k'(x_1^{p^{-m}},...,x_n^{p^{-m}})$ and thus that every finite extension of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is contained in a finite and separable extension of $k'[x_1^{p^{-m}},...,x_n^{p^{-m}}]$. But that part I understand. Read again my two questions. I can't deduce an answer from your comment. e.g. the problem in Q_1 is not why $L/I/K$ but why $EF$. It suggest to me that $E$ is not neccessary contained in $F$. That's strange.